# PHP SQL SELECT and then UPDATE the value

Tags: php, sql, datetime-format

I have a problem.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$res2 = $_data['DateSubmitted'];
//res2 returns 2014-08-31 12:03:02
$res3 = $_data['UserIp'];
//res3 returns 109.173.20.143 for example

$resdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($res2));

$SubmId = $db->query("SELECT `SubmissionId` FROM `rrr_submissions` WHERE `FormId` = '20' AND `DateSubmitted`='".$resdate."' AND `UserIp`='".$res3."'");

$db->setQuery("UPDATE `rrr_submission_values` SET `FieldValue` = '".$SubmId."' WHERE `FieldName`='7_Status' AND `SubmissionId`='5682'");

$db->query();
```

In rrr_submissions:

- SubmissionId is INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
- FormId is INT(11)
- **DateSubmitted is datetime**
- UserIp is varchar(15)

In rrr_submission_values:

- FieldValue is text
- FieldName is text
- SubmissionId is int(11)

What am I do wrong? In the result I see "1" in the FieldValue.

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and how does that differ from the results you see now? What have you tried to fix the problem, and how did that attempt fail?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I want the first SELECT query to select the "SubmissionId" value from "rrr_submissions" table. Then I want to set this value to the variable $SubmId. And the last step I want to update the value in the table "rrr_submission_values"

Comment: To fix the problem I tried to check all of variables ($res2, $res3, $resdate, $SubmId). I changed step by step the value "FieldValue" to see what it returns. For example: $db->setQuery("UPDATE `rrr_submission_values` SET `FieldValue` = '".$res2."' WHERE `FieldName`='7_Status' AND `SubmissionId`='5682'");

Comment: Every variable returns OK, except $SubmId. It returns "1". I searched google for 2 days and I've found that the problem is in the type of "DateSubmitted". It is "datetime".

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the result row and then calling the field value.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$res2 = $_data['DateSubmitted'];
//res2 returns 2014-08-31 12:03:02
$res3 = $_data['UserIp'];
//res3 returns 109.173.20.143 for example

$resdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_data['DateSubmitted']));

$SubmId = $db->query("SELECT `SubmissionId` FROM `rrr_submissions` WHERE `FormId` = '20' AND `DateSubmitted`='".$resdate."' AND `UserIp`='".$res3."'");

$row = $db->loadRow();

$SubmId = $row['SubmissionId'];

$db->setQuery("UPDATE `rrr_submission_values` SET `FieldValue` = '".$SubmId."' WHERE `FieldName`='7_Status' AND `SubmissionId`='5682'");

$db->query();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to add this code, but now it returns nothing at all.

Comment: It's a mistake somewhere. Now I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: I think the problem is in data type mismatch. The **DateSubmitted** is  **datatime** and the **$_data['DateSubmitted']** is **text** or **int** I think. I don't know exactly but it's differ from datetime type. So I dont't know how to fix it.

Comment: If you want the data type in the database to be different, change it using an ALTER statement. If you want to convert the text or int data in `$_data['DateSubmitted']` into a datetime, convert it in your UPDATE statement.

Comment: If you `echo $SubmId;` what does it output?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `$resdate` which is exactly the same, or at least expected, output as `$res2`. Why not use `$res2` which is already set up how you require it?